# Clang-format AlignConsecutiveDeclarations weird behaviour

Tags: c++, clang-format

When AlignConsecutiveDeclarations is set to true, some function parameters get weirdly aligned:

```
ErrorType Layer::Construct(AbstractManagedObject*                      a_parent,
                           container::Map<utf8::String, utf8::String>& a_configuration_attributess, uint8_t a_opacity)
```

I would like variable declarations to be aligned, but not parameter lists. I wouldn't mind the alignment in the parameter list if the second line had only one parameter.

Is this intended behaviour? Any way around it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations` will also align function parameters. I wasn't sure about it at first, and [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) is not very clear on this, too, but reading through clang-format's [source code](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Format/WhitespaceManager.cpp), it's clear that function parameters alignment is by design:

```
void WhitespaceManager::alignConsecutiveDeclarations() {
  ...
  AlignTokens(Style,
              [](Change const &C) {
                return C.Tok->is(TT_StartOfName) ||             // <-- variables
                       C.Tok->is(TT_FunctionDeclarationName) || // <-- parameters
                       C.Tok->is(tok::kw_operator);
              },
  ...
```

The exact alignment in your example, I wasn't able to reproduce (tried clang-format 5.0, 6.0) - for me, it placed each function parameter in a single line:

```
ErrorType Layer::Construct(
    AbstractManagedObject *                     a_parent,
    container::Map<utf8::String, utf8::String> &a_configuration_attributess,
    uint8_t                                     a_opacity);
```

It's possible that `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true` conflicts with some other parameter in your clang-format configuration, which gives the result you're seeing. Make sure that `BinPackParameters` is set to `false` - this should force splitting of function parameters into separate lines if the column limit is exceeded:

> **BinPackParameters** (bool)
>
> If false, a function declaration’s or function definition’s parameters will either all be on the same line or will have one line each.

If you wish to avoid function parameters alignment altogether, and willing to downgrade your clang-format version, you could use clang-format 4.0.
The `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations` option was introduced in version 3.8, and back then, it did not align function parameters - just consecutive variable declarations. Feeding your example to clang-format 3.8 gives the following result:

```
ErrorType Layer::Construct(
    AbstractManagedObject *a_parent,
    container::Map<utf8::String, utf8::String> &a_configuration_attributess,
    uint8_t a_opacity);
```

In following versions, 3.9 and 4.0, functionality of the `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations` parameter remained the same. Starting clang-format 5.0, functionality has changed, and it started aligning function parameters, too.